# Workflow not Appearing on Associated List after Creation

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow

I have now tried multiple times to create a new workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 by doing the following:

**1**

- Select the list
- Under workflows, click 'New'
- Create the workflow

**2**

- Select the list
- Click 'List Workflow'
- Create the workflow from here

**3**

- Select 'Workflows'
- Click 'Reusable Workflow'
- Create the workflow

I can see all of the created workflows under the 'Workflows' section on the left, and when I click 'Associated List' from inside any of the workflows, it takes me to the correct list.

However, when I look at the list in SharePoint Designer, or when I create a new item (which should start the workflow), nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea why this may not be working? I have created workflows on this site in the past without this issue, and I can't think of anything off the top of my head that has changed which would prevent me from doing so again.

**Please let me know if I can provide any additional details or screenshots and I will do so**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was publish the workflow and then it started working